# New value from ThreadLocal<IDisposable> after .Value.Dispose()

Tags: c#, multithreading, idisposable, thread-local

Is there a built-in `ThreadLocal<T>`-like construct for sharing an object within each unique thread but recreating it if the original value was disposed/destructed/teared down/nulled?

Here's my attempt at implementing such behaviour with `ConcurrentDictionary` (the `ThreadLocalDisposable2` below), but I was hoping to just use `ThreadLocal<T>` (as in `ThreadLocalDisposable1`), however I can't get the `Foo` test to pass, `.Values.Remove(this)` doesn't do what I was hoping it would do and still causes `ObjectDisposedException`.

```
public class Class1
{
    [Test]
    public void Foo()
    {
        using (var foo = ThreadLocalDisposable1.Get())
            foo.Foo();

        using (var foo = ThreadLocalDisposable1.Get())
            foo.Foo();
    }

    [Test]
    public void Bar()
    {
        using (var bar = ThreadLocalDisposable2.Get())
            bar.Foo();

        using (var bar = ThreadLocalDisposable2.Get())
            bar.Foo();
    }
}
```

**[1]**

```
public class ThreadLocalDisposable1 : IDisposable
{
    private Stream _foo;

    private static ThreadLocal<ThreadLocalDisposable1> _thread;

    static ThreadLocalDisposable1()
    {
        _thread = new ThreadLocal<ThreadLocalDisposable1>(() => new ThreadLocalDisposable1(), true);
    }

    private ThreadLocalDisposable1()
    {
        _foo = new MemoryStream();
    }

    public static ThreadLocalDisposable1 Get()
    {
        return _thread.Value;
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        _foo.WriteByte(1);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        //I do not think it means what I think it means
        _thread.Values.Remove(this);

        _foo.Dispose();
    }
}
```

**[2]**

```
public class ThreadLocalDisposable2 : IDisposable
{
    private Stream _foo;
    private int _thread;

    private static ConcurrentDictionary<int, ThreadLocalDisposable2> _threads;

    static ThreadLocalDisposable2()
    {
        _threads = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, ThreadLocalDisposable2>();
    }

    private ThreadLocalDisposable2(int thread)
    {
        _thread = thread;
        _foo = new MemoryStream();
    }

    public static ThreadLocalDisposable2 Get()
    {
        return _threads.GetOrAdd(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, i => new ThreadLocalDisposable2(i));
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        _foo.WriteByte(1);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        ThreadLocalDisposable2 thread;
        _threads.TryRemove(_thread, out thread);

        _foo.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Edit:

Just to clarify what I mean, basically I want all of the behaviour of `ThreadLocal` but when I call `Dispose` (on the value, the `ThreadLocalDisposable*` with underlying `Stream` in this example, not the static `ThreadLocal` itself) take that disposed instance out of circulation, i.e. if called upon again -- create a new value as if it's a brand new thread requiring a brand new instance.

The `ThreadLocalDisposable1`, **[1]**, is sample class of what I think should've worked, except the `.Values.Remove(this)` line doesn't "take it out of circulation" and forces a new instance to be created for that thread.

The `ThreadLocalDisposable2`, **[2]**, with `ConcurrentDictionary`, is a way I implemented alternative to ThreadLocal with "take out of circulation" behaviour I'm after.

Edit:

This is not the a real use case I have, just a general example I can think of, but if you have for example a static `ThreadLocal<SqlConnection>`, or a socket, and it's forcefully closed (and disposed in final block) -- drop that connection instance and create a new one transparently if called again.

Comment: maybe I did not get the idea but are you using a concurrentdictionary marked as threadlocal?

Comment: @daryal No, I'm using it instead of, see `ThreadLocalDisposable2`. I'd like to use `ThreadLocal` but I can't quite make it work, so I have `ConcurrentDictionary` that works as I want, but feels hacky.

Comment: It's hard to imagine what you're trying to do here. I would suggest, though, that you create a class that contains the thing you want to make disposable, and make a `ThreadLocal` instance of that class. Handle the disposal/recreation logic inside the class rather than trying to manage a dictionary of `ThreadLocal` instances.

Comment: @JimMischel please see the edit, hopefully it's a bit clearer now. There is no dictionary of ThreadLocal instances.

Comment: @IlyaKozhevnikov 1. its usually better to edit the post, than to explain in the comments. 2. what are you trying to actually do? this sounds like a pretty bad idea...

Comment: @AK_ why is it a bad idea? It's *ThreadLocal-except-if-disposed*. This is not the a real use case I have, just an example, but if you have for example a static `ThreadLocal<SqlConnection>`, or a socket, and it's forcefully closed (and disposed in final block) -- drop that connection instance and create a new one.

Comment: Usually, especially with the new magical world of Tasks, you want to have more fine grained control over objects like SqlConnection or Socket. Also, doing stuff like `SomeStaticClass.GetThreadSocket()` is pretty bad, fragile(closure) , and un-testable.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're making this much harder than it has to be. Consider this:

```
public class MyClass: IDisposable
{
    private Stream _foo;

    public MyClass Get()
    {
        if (_foo == null)
        {
            _foo = new MemoryStream();
        }
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        _foo.WriteByte(1);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_foo != null)
        {
            _foo.Dispose();
            _foo = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you can create one of those:

```
ThreadLocal<MyClass> MyThing = new ThreadLocal<MyClass>();
```

And you can write:

```
using (MyThing.Value.Get())
{
    // do stuff
}
```

That seems functionally equivalent to what you're trying to do with your `ConcurrentDictionary` stuff.

That said, it seems like this is something that would be better managed another way. I don't know your application so I can't say for sure, but it seems like a bad idea to have a stateful object like a `Stream` or `SqlConnection` as a global variable. Usually those things are job-specific rather than thread-specific, and as such should be passed as parameters when you start the job.

Comment: Interesting... inside out ThreadLocal with a nonstatic Lazy "singleton"... I haven't thought about it like that. It's not ideal cause it exposes all the `System.Threading` innards rather that being completely transparent to the caller. I'll give it a go and see if I can backport it, thank you.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that it's not really disposing of the `MyClass`, just swaps out the `Stream`, so although it works in this simplified example when `MyClass` has other data, e.g. an instance field that's written to stream instead of 1, it will result in unspecified behaviour. So... I'd say it's not really functionally equivalent to the `ConcurrentDictionary` stuff.

Comment: @IlyaKozhevnikov: No, it's not disposing of the `MyClass` instance. That was kind of my point: to create a persistent object to wrap the disposable things.

Comment: @IlyaKozhevnikov `MyClass` is just a wrapper around whatever you want to have inside. Just make it a sealed generic class and be done with it, it's just a helper class, not something you're going to modify, ever. If you want extra state information that disappears when you call `Dispose`... make that a new class, and use `MyClass` as a wrapper around that. Try looking up "composition", it's a rather useful pattern.